# Questions about while loop and def function

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I have a question regarding the loop. When I run the loop, my "count" is equal to two while it seems like it runs through it for three-time (the properties_list located in the shell appears three times). My goal is to make the code for example the first containers meet the criteria of the if-statement, then print "success" and repeat the process, until false in the if-statement. Can you give me some tips on that? Thanks!

```
def get_mass(container_list)
    current_mass=0
    current_mass=container_list[-1][1]
    return current_massenter 
def detect_container():
    properties_list=[]
    count=0
    total_mass=0
    added_mass=0
    while count<3:
        container=random.randint(1,6)
        current_container=table.dispense_container(container,True)
        print ("current container:", current_container)
        properties_list.append(current_container)
        print("properties_list", properties_list)
        added_mass=get_mass(properties_list)
        total_mass=total_mass+added_mass
        print("added_mass:",added_mass)
        print("total mass:", total_mass)

        if total_mass<90 and properties_list[0][2]==properties_list[-1][2]:
            #load_container(count)
            print("success")
            count=count+1
        else:
            print ("end")
            break
    return count
```

Here is the python shell looks like:

```
>>> detect_container()
current container: ('paper', 48.23733148585649, 'Bin04')
properties_list: [('paper', 48.23733148585649, 'Bin04')]
added_mass: 48.23733148585649 
total mass: 48.23733148585649 
current container: ('plastic', 31.348778344676226, 'Bin04')
properties_list: [('paper', 48.23733148585649, 'Bin04'), ('plastic', 31.348778344676 
226, 'Bin04')]
added_mass: 31.348778344676226 
total mass: 79.5861098305327
current container: ('paper', 25.449467465258202, 'Bin04')
properties_list: [('paper', 48.23733148585649, 'Bin04'), ('plastic', 31.348778344676 
226, 'Bin04'), ('paper', 25.449467465258202, 'Bin04')]
added_mass: 25.449467465258202 
total mass: 105.03557729579092 
end
2
```

In case you wondering what is table.dispense_container(randint, True) is:

When this function is called, a container is spawned onto the table depending on the value
variable  inputted.  A  valid  value  is  a  number  between  1  and  6  (inclusive)  and  each  value
coincides to a container with distinct properties. 1, 2 & 3 corresponds to plastic, metal, and
paper  containers,  respectively,  that  are  non-contaminated,  and  4,  5  &  6  corresponds  to
plastic, metal, and paper containers, respectively, that are contaminated.
Setting properties to the Boolean True will also return the container material, mass (in grams)
of  the  container,  as  well  as  the  bin  ID  (where  the  container  needs  to  be  dropped  off).  By
default, the function returns no properties.

For example: When I type number 6 in the function --> `table.dispense_container(6, True)`
The output is: `('paper','59.32860054161556','Bin04')`

Comment: Print the value of count on each pass through the loop. Do you see the values you expected to?

Comment: the loop runs for count value 0, 1, and 2. That said, it is unclear what "tips" you expect. What specific problem you are unable to solve? Please, check [ask].

Comment: You run your loop three times.  `count` has the values 0, 1, and 2.  You finish on the third loop and return the current value of `count` which is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the condition is met, and it will help you to print "success" and repeat the process, until false in the if-statement. Let me know if it doesn't help.

```
if total_mass<90 and properties_list[0][2]==properties_list[-1][2]:
```